# EDIT: Airflow GCSToS3Operator: keep_directory_structure=True is not being passed in the rendered template, prefix is being added in the dest_s3_key

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am running the task in composer with Composer version: 2.0.18 and Airflow version: 2.2.5

I am sending data to the AWS S3 from Google GCS. For which I am using GCSToS3Operator with the parameters as follow(with example) I have stored AWS credentials in Airflow Connections with connection id "S3-action-outbound"

```
gcs_to_s3 = GCSToS3Operator(
        task_id="gcs_to_s3",
        bucket="gcs_outbound",
        prefix="legacy/action/20220629",
        delimiter=".csv",
        dest_aws_conn_id="S3-action-outbound",
        dest_s3_key="s3a://action/daily/",
        replace=False,
        keep_directory_structure=True,
    )
```

But in the end result it's copying the prefix as well. it's writing data at location: `s3a://action/daily/legacy/action/20220629/test1.csv`

I just want to add the data to the location which I have added `s3a://action/daily/test1.csv`

according to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/gcs_to_s3/index.html) if `keep_directory_structure= False` only then it's suppose to copy the directory path. I tried making it false and it copied the path twice for example it did like this: `s3a://action/daily/legacy/action/20220629/legacy/action/20220629/test1.csv`

**EDIT:**
I just realized that there is an issue with the airflow not taking the variable from template. find the attached screenshot of the rendered template[image]

It did not took the variable `replace` and `keep_directory_structure`

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @pas, nope I haven't found any solution so far. It still copies the entire path. The thing I did was to add another temporary path from which I sent data to S3 once data sent to S3. I copied data from gcp temporary path to the one I wanted for my final storage.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion about it in the PR when keep_directory_structure was added.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22071/files

it was not implement as in gcs_to_sftp.py